# Stripping special characters in R

Tags: r

I have the following string

```
> str    
[1]  "[ { \"category\" : \"book\"} , { \"category\" : \"Movie\"} , { \"category\" : \"Brand\"}]"
```

I want to strip it to get the following vector

```
> a
[1] "book" "Movie" "Brand"
```

My problem is how to handle the "" and \ within the string to pass it to either **grep** or **gsub** in R. This is what I did and I get an error

```
> grep("^\[ \{ \\"category\\" : \\"([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)\\".*",str)
Error: '\[' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "^\["
```

Am I even on the right track?

Comment: Is the format JSON? Then maybe the RJSONIO package may be helpful.

Comment: There are no backslashes in your string. They are only put there by R to show you that there are quotes in your string. This info might be useful if Karsten's JSON hint doesn't work out (which it should, it looks like JSON to me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the `rjson` package will sort you out:

```
> require(rjson)
> unlist(fromJSON(str))
  category category category 
    "book"  "Movie"  "Brand"
```

ignoring the names ("category") that's what you want. Wrap in `as.vector()` to get rid of those.

Comment: @Spacedman you can ged rid of names with "use.names=FALSE" in unlist function.